# Only positive lyapunov exponents for a solution assumed to be a limited set

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, nonlinear-dynamics

I have a problem characterizing the solution of a dynamic system. It is a system of four nonlinear differential equations of first order. The considered solution shows:

- For the selected initial conditions a stable behavior (very long simulation durations show a limited set).
- However, the calculated Lyapunov spectrum shows only positive exponents (+69,+59,+41,+31).
- This autocorrelation:
  [image: Autocorrelation]
- I know, the Poincaré–Bendixson theorem is only valid for two dimensional systems, but nevertheless at initial conditions (with a much larger value than the assumed to be limited set), the trajectory converges to the limited set.

Assuming the calculation of the Lyapunov spectrum (I validated the code with known systems) and the autocorrelation are correct, what does this mean for the solution? Does this mean that it is not a limited set, so for $t$ against infinity the amplitude would increase?
The Lyapunov exponents seem very large to me, shouldn't one see such a rise in a long simulation time?

Answer (score 1):

Your observations contradict each other.
A system with only positive Lyapunov exponents should exhibit an unbounded dynamics.
Given the time scale on which your dynamics appears to act (as per the autocorrelation), even one Lyapunov exponent of the order of magnitude you are reporting seems questionably high, as it should lead to a quick effects within a few time units.

Moreover your plot of the autocorrelation function does not allow to make any conclusions as to whether it decays (chaos) or not (periodic or quasiperiodic dynamics).

Comment: The system I am investigating has a negative velocity proportional therm and is therefore instable. Due to an event-controlled function that is triggered at a certain amplitude, the amplitude is greatly reduced. Then, due to the negative velocity proportional terms, the amplitude increases again, up to the amplitude given by the event, when the amplitude is strongly reduced again. This means that there are no amplitudes greater than the amplitude at which the event function strikes.

Comment: Would one not call such a system stable? I would because a certain amplitude is not exceeded? Or is only the Lyapunov stability not correct here, because most of the time an instable behaviour can be observed (only positiv Lyapunov exponents), which is reduced to smaller amplitudes only by an event?

Comment: @Dnamix: If you have a system with such dynamical events, you have to  include these when calculating the Lyapunov exponents. Otherwise it’s no wonder your results do not agree.

Comment: The events are included in the simulation. I am using a Methode based on the Gram-Schmidt Orthonormalization. This means that the system is simulated for a very long time (with all events) and the Lyapunov exponents are calculated repeatedly to converge with time. I can also see in the Simulations that the limit amplitude is not exceeded. The Lyapnuov exponents still show such high values.

Comment: @Dnamix: Then you likely made a mistake somewhere.